# Failed to Login using sqllite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to android development. So I am trying to implement a signup and login page using Sqlite as the database. But after writing the database code and the login activity code. Instead of it to proceed to another activity after logging in, it is implementing the else code instead.
Take a look at the code below

**Database code**

```
//Check if user exist from Database
public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

    //array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {Constant.USER_ID};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    //selection Criteria
    String selection = Constant.USER_EMAIL + " =?" + " AND " + Constant.USER_PASSWORD + " =?";

    //selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

    //Query user table with conditions
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constant.USER_TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null,null,null);

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Login Activity code**

```
private void proceedToLogin(String email, String password)
{
    boolean login = myDb.checkUser(email, password);
    if (login) {
        proceedToDashBoard();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like there is no such user in the DB. Inspect your DB first.

Comment: Also, inspect the values for `email` and `password`.

Comment: Thanks @VladyslavMatviienko I made sure i registered the usrname in the database first. check out the code for registering below

Comment: edit the question and add the code there, don't try to put it in comments. As you can see - it works terrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the user you are authenticating does not exist in the db, or the method you wrote to insert user to db isn't correct.  You can debug this by putting break points at the part where you are sending credentials to the db to check for any nulls.

Additionally, you can access the SQLite db and check presence of any data through the following way: device explorer(bottom right of android studio) >data>data>com.yourpackage.name>databases  and there you will find your db. Ensure usb debugging is active and you have connected your phone.

Download the DB and use online [sqlite browser](https://sqliteonline.com/) to view its contents.
You can also check [this](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-login-and-register-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/) article for Signup and login using sqlite.

Comment: Thank you @simon . The problem seems to be that I was calling the wrong constructor in the registration activity. How i happened to miss this still beats me. Thank you code now working perfectly